# Facing issue with JOLT transformation with nested array

Tags: json, jolt

I have a JSON **input** :

```json
{
  "id": "Root_ID",
  "Item": [
    {
      "id": "ID_1",
      "characteristic": [
        {
          "name": "char1",
          "value": "PRE1"
        },
        {
          "name": "char2",
          "value": "2050-01-01"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "ID_2",
      "characteristic": [
        {
          "name": "char1",
          "value": "PRE2"
        },
        {
          "name": "char2",
          "value": "2050-01-02"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

which needs to be converted by using a Jolt transformation spec to the following **output** :

```json
{
  "id": "Root_ID",
  "Item": [
    {
      "id": "ID_1",
      "char1": "PRE1",
      "char2": "2050-01-01"
    },
    {
      "id": "ID_2",
      "char1": "PRE2",
      "char2": "2050-01-02"
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently, I'm using this spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "Item": {
        "*": {
          "characteristic": {
            "*": {
              "name": {
                "char1": {
                  "@(2,value)": "item[#3].char1"
                },
                "char2": {
                  "@(2,value)": "item[#3].char2"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which does not produce the desired result.

Can you please help me prepare a correct spec to handle this issue ?

**Edit** : What if I'd like to get the following JSON result ?

```json
{
  "id": "Root_ID",
  "Item": [
    {
      "id": "ID_1",
      "char1": "PRE1"
    },
    {
      "id": "ID_2",
      "char1": "PRE2",
      "char2": "2050-01-02"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec in which ***@value*** and ***@name*** are matched reciprocally such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "&",
      "Item": {
        "*": {
          "id": "&2[&1].&",// you can reduce two levels based on the inner identifier 4,3 -> 2,1
          "char*": {
            "*": {
              "@value": "&4[&3].@name" // &4 copies the literal "Item" after going four levels up the tree, [&3] generates array-wise result(array of objects) after going three levels up the tree to reach the level of the indexes of the "Item" array
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit** : You can alternatively use the following spec for the case in which you need to return **`char2`** within the all objects but the first :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "&",
      "Item": {
        "0": {// stands for the first index
          "id": "&2[&1].&",
          "char*": {
            "*": {
              "name": {
                "char1": {
                  "@2,value": "&6[&5].@3,name"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "*": {
          "id": "&2[&1].&",
          "char*": {
            "*": {
              "@value": "&4[&3].@name"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros it worked but need help with selected item value not all with separate Items (Expected output)
`{
  "id" : "Root_ID",
  "Item" : [ {
    "id": "ID_1",
    "char1" : "PRE1"
  }, {
    "id": "ID_2",
    "char1" : "PRE2",
    "char2" : "2050-01-02"
  } ]
}`